# Compute work required to wind a chain onto a cylinder using a​ winch

Tags: integration

I'm trying to set up the integral for the following problem:

A 70-m-long chain hangs vertically from a cylinder attached to a winch. Assume there is no friction in the system and that the chain has a density of 7​kg/m. Use 9.8 m/s^2 for the acceleration due to gravity.

a. How much work is required to wind the entire chain onto the cylinder using the​ winch?

b. How much work is required to wind the chain onto the cylinder if a 45​-kg block is attached to the end of the​ chain?

I solved a), which is 7 * 9.8 (70-y)dy

=> Integral of (4802 - 68.6y)dy from 0 to 70.

Now for b), I thought it would be 4802 - 68.6y + 45 => 4847 - 68.6y, but it turned out it's not the correct set up.

What am I missing?

Comment: You want the force, not the weight

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Can you elaborate?

Comment: $45$ kgs is the weight of the object; you want the work done by the $force$ of gravity, which is $450$N

Comment: I'm only trying to set up the integral, not solve the work. I'm new to these problems so I may need clarification if possible. 4802 - 68.6y + 450? How did you get that number?

Comment: The force you must exert would be given by $4802-68.6y+45*9.8$. So just to correct my earlier comment, I meant $45*9.8$N, but what I actually took the value to be was $45*10$N

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Work by definition:
$$W = \int_{}^{} {dW}  = \int_0^L {F(x)dx}= $$
if the raise is quasi-static, the force applied is equal and opposite to the weight of the chain's free end,
$$F(x) = m(x)g = \lambda (L - x)g$$
solving the integral,
$$ = \lambda g\int_{}^{} {(L - x)dx}  = \lambda g{L^2}/2$$
for (b) use,
$$m(x) = \lambda (L - x)g + {m_0}$$

Comment: Thank you for the info! I kind of had an idea but missed what AnotherJohnDoe pointed out.